# Rapidminer - Spliting rows that has values in wrong type

Tags: attributes, data-mining, rapidminer

I had a data set of 8 millon rows in a txt file with tab delimited format without quotes.
I had 5 of the 14 columns with date values in dd.MM.yyyy format.

**Problem 1**
I am trying to import the file. In "Format your colums" step, if I choose the type of that colums as "date", it gives errors and all cells in columns turns "?"

So I selected "polynomial" and planed to convert attribute type to date later.

**Problem 2 (the real one)**
I imported the data and put "nominal to date" operator. When I run I got error in line 14.899:

```
Cannot parse date: Unparseable date: "0"
```

I find the line and I see that columns separated wrong. There was a tab character in a string in the a prior cell. So values moved one cell right. And this row was not the only one that moved.

I want to split the rows that has the values in wrong data type for spesified attributes. So I cant correct them manually.

How can I do that in Rapidminer?

Or any other ideas to figure theese problems out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a broken input file.

The best solution, obviously, is to fix the process that generates the data. Espace or replace tab characters and format the date in a non-ambiguous format such as the ISO date format.

Assuming that you can't fix the date, you should probably write a *robust* parser *program* yourself. A generic parser such as rapidminer's won't be able to fix every problem.

Answer (score 2):

so most likely you need to adjust the date formatting in this pull-down menu:

[image]

To be honest, I usually just import as polynominal and then convert to date in my process. It's easier and reproducable.